# function within a function, arrays, Julia

Tags: julia

I have the first function using `!` and I want to get the multiplication of succrate and price in a second function, calling the initial function. What is the syntax? Thanks

```
length_of_arrays = 101

lower_limit = 0
steps_per_unit = 1

price1 = 10

succrate1 = 5
succrate2 = 7

price = Array{Float64, 1}(101)
succrate = Array{Float64, 2}(101,20)    


function modifyarrays!(length_of_arrays, price, lower_limit, steps_per_unit, succrate)
for pr_A in 1:101

price[pr_A] = lower_limit + ((pr_A-1) / steps_per_unit)

  for d in 1:20
    if price[pr_A] == price1
        succrate[pr_A, d] = succrate1
    else
        succrate[pr_A, d] = succrate2
    end
  end
 end

end

modifyarrays!(101, price, 0, 1, succrate)
```

Comment: make your question as abstract and clear as you can, and describe the exact problem you have. Maybe show what you want in another language you know, like Java, or Python, or anything else so that we know the syntax your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
function set_price_at!(price, pr_A, lower_limit, steps_per_unit) 
    price[pr_A] = lower_limit + ((pr_A-1) / steps_per_unit)
    nothing
end

function set_succrate_at!(succrate, pr_A, price, succrate1, succrate2)
    set_price_at!(price, pr_A, lower_limit, steps_per_unit) # You could call it here (1)
    for d in 1:20
        if price[pr_A] == price1
            succrate[pr_A, d] = succrate1
        else
            succrate[pr_A, d] = succrate2
        end
    end
end

function modifyarrays!(length_of_arrays, price, lower_limit, steps_per_unit, succrate)
    for pr_A in 1:101
        # set_price_at!(price, pr_A, lower_limit, steps_per_unit) # or here (2)
        set_succrate_at!(succrate, pr_A, price, succrate1, succrate2)
    end
end

price = rand(Float64, (101,))
succrate = rand(Float64, (101,20))

modifyarrays!(101, price, 0, 1, succrate)
```

I like to call function at (2) more than call it at (1).

Comment: Ok thanks. I understand what you are saying. But is there a way to call a particular array from the function in another function? for example I have a 2 dimensional array that must call price[] from the first function and then multiply it with another array. Therefore, I have to call the price function and particularly the price array as it is used in the calculation in a multiplication.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what you want to do... :/

Comment: For example If I wanted to multiply succrate with a 2d array in another function e.g.     probabilities[i, d] = succrate[i] ^ (d-1) * price[i] how should I call the function arguments succrate, price in the current function?

Comment: Maybe if you create (in your question) example where functions will be named `current_function` and `another_function` and put comment in body of `current_function` where you like to call something from `another_function` (and maybe comment in that function too if there is something you want to like see in `current_function`) it start to be less nonsensical (for me)...